# Schedule Windows Task to open a page with username and passowrd

Tags: php, windows, cron, task, html

How would you run a windows task schedule to open a webpage, post login information and then run the url?

Background:

CRM has crons that were setup for a linux only.  It has a manager where I can run the jobs as well manually.  I want to run the web url that does these jobs manually through the windows server but requires that each time it connect it login with a specific user.

How would I setup a scheduled task on windows server that :
1. Opens and Logs into page then runs the url for the manual job.

2. Runs every minute

So essentially it needs to look like this:

```
http://thewebsitename.com/?username=someuser&password=apass
http://thewebsitename.com/theurltorunjobmanually.php
```

Can scheduled tasks run a php command instead as well? For example if I set up a WGET script, could the scheduler run that php script?  Have not been able to figure out how to do this, linux seems to be pretty easy in this scenario

Comment: what? password as a get parameter? there goes all the thousands of hours spent on securing websites..

Comment: internal network, off internet.  Server is non accessible to public.  As for the get variables, just an example to show what needs to be done to post data to the login script before we can run  the command.  The method behind how it is done is not necessary, just need to know how to open a page to login to a site then run a url.

Comment: i understand. My goal was not to make fun. it is just not a good practice. You can POST with valid parameters. Example, use `Curl` -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17783931/1628832

Comment: What i need is not a php curl script as that is not a problem to write , what I needs is for windows to run these tasks automatically server side through the task scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as simple as:

- [Download wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)
- Create a batch file with the following contents:

```
wget --post-data "username=someuser&password=apass" http://thewebsitename.com/
wget http://thewebsitename.com/theurltorunjobmanually.php
```

You also asked about running a PHP script via the scheduled task, you can add this line to the batch script:

```
C:\path\to\PHP.exe script.php
```

Comment: I will try this, as this seems to be the simplest.  If this works I will mark this as answered.

Comment: This would have worked if not for the security built into the CRM itself. For anyone else not having to worry about unique security tokens generated first before sending user and pass to mysql database this will be your answer.  I have marked this as answer as this should help someone in the future.

Comment: I had to do automated logins to a Joomla CMS once, they used security tokens as well so I had to code something more complicated in PHP.

Comment: think I will just write a VBscript which I can run in the scheduler.  Making miss the days of linux haha.  Thanks for the help though this was a great answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for methodology or an actual solution, but we have a process somewhat like this where we need to login to our CRM and run an upload, task creation process at regular intervals. Used to be manual but now we use an automation software product, Foxtrot. You can find it here for whatever it is worth: http://www.enablesoft.com/foxtrot-professional/

Comment: The app it self seems great, but looking for something that is already built into windows as 1 grand for automating tasks seems pretty high when the windows task scheduler seems pretty adept to what we should be able to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the cURL or wget commands in a batch file or PowerShell script and have the Windows Task Scheduler call it.